# How to find the second lowest and second highest number in a user-inputted list using loops and no arrays

Tags: java, loops, java.util.scanner

For my program, I need to find the highest pair and lowest pair from 8 user-inputted ints, I am required to use a loop and no arrays.
Ex. 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13 should return: (13, 12) , (6, 7)

How should I go about finding the second highest and second lowest number using a loop?

Comment: What do you mean by "highest pair and lowest pair"? Does their sum make them the lowest/highest pair?

Comment: @GaryJohnson I mean the two highest numbers and the two lowest numbers.

Comment: It might help to think through how you'd do it with the numbers in an array.  Either way, you need a loop.  The only difference is that instead of the loop taking elements from an array, it takes them right from the keyboard.

Comment: It might also help to think about how you'd find just the highest and lowest numbers.  Get that to work, and then think about how you can change it to also find the second-highest and second-lowest.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you would find the lowest number in a users input without an array.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int lowest;
for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    int temp = sc.nextInt();
    if(i == 0) lowest = temp;
    else if(lowest > temp) lowest = temp;    
}

return lowest;
```

Now this can also be used to find the highest number by just switching the `>` symbol in the `else if` to `<` and you will find the greatest number in the input.

You can then use this process to find the lowest and highest pairs by adding more variables.

Answer (score 0):

I'd look for the highest and the lowest values and keep track of the previous highest and lowest value, something like this:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

    public static void findMaxMinPairs() {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    int min1=Integer.MAX_VALUE;int min2=Integer.MAX_VALUE; int max1=Integer.MIN_VALUE; int max2=Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    while (scanner.hasNext()) {
    int curr = scanner.nextInt();
        if(curr < min1){
            min2 = min1;       
            min1 = curr;

        }else if(curr < min2) {
               min2 = curr;
        }
        if(curr > max1){
          max2 = max1;       
          max1 = curr;
        }else if(curr >max2) {
          max2 = curr;
        }
   }
   System.out.println("("+min1+","+min2+") ,("+max1+","+max2+")");
   scanner.close();

  }
```

Answer (score -1):

Read your integers into an array

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
int[] array = new int[8];

for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    array[i] = Integer.parseInt(scanner.next());
}
```

Sort the array

```
Arrays.sort(array);
```

Print the 4 integers you are interested in

```
int min1 = array[0];
int min2 = array[1];
int max1 = array[6];
int max2 = array[7];

System.out.println("(" + max2 + "," + max1 + "), (" + min1 + "," + min2 + ")");
```

Comment: The question specifically says that arrays aren't allowed.